# Yii2 Apply a function to all requests

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Is there any way to apply a function to all requests and queries in Yii2?

I want to replace specific characters for all of them.

I am using Yii2 advanced app

Thanks.

This is the config file:

```
$config = [
    'language' => 'en',
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'something',
        ],
        'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
            'defaultRoles' => ['guest'],
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
        ],
    ],
];

return $config;
```

Answer (score 7):

Without extending custom code on each request can be exexuted like so (add this to your application config):

```
return [        
    'on beforeRequest' => function () {
        if (!Yii::$app->get('user', false)) {
            return;
        }

        $user = User::getCurrent();
        if ($user) {
            Yii::$app->setTimeZone($user->time_zone);
        }
    },
    'on afterRequest' => function () {
        ...
    },
];
```

Depending on when you need to execute code (before or after the request) use `'on beforeRequest'` or `'on afterRequest'` accordingly.

Comment: I have added the config file content.
Would you please show me how should I change it?

Answer (score 2):

yii2 have a [request component](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-request.html). You can extend `yii\web\request` and define your custom implementation.

```
[
    ...
    'components' =>
        'request' => [
            'class' => '\common\MyRequest',
            'addGeoLocationForExample' => true,
        ]
        ...
```